# Vector dot product along one dimension for multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra, theano

I want to compute the sum product along **one** dimension of two multidimensional arrays, using Theano.

I'll describe precisely what I want to do using `numpy` first. `numpy.tensordot` and `numpy.dot` seem to always do a *matrix* product, whereas I'm in essence looking for a batched equivalent of a *vector* product. Given `x` and `y`, I want to compute `z` like so:

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(200, 2, 2, 1000))
y = np.random.normal(size=(200, 2, 2))

# this is how I now approach it:
z = np.sum(y[:,:,:,np.newaxis] * x, axis=1)

# z is of shape (200, 2, 1000)
```

Now I know that `numpy.einsum` would probably be able to help me here, but again, I want to do this particular computation in **Theano**, which does not have an `einsum` equivalent. I will need to use `dot`, `tensordot`, or Theano's specialized einsum subset functions `batched_dot` or `batched_tensordot`.

The reason I'm looking to change my approach to this is performance; I suspect that using builtin (CUDA) dot products will be faster than relying on broadcasting, element-wise product, and sum.

Comment: I think because of the axis alignment requirement along the first axis, you might want to expand dimensions and sum, just like you are doing here.

Comment: Just for sake of completeness, an einsum solution would look like `z2 = numpy.einsum('ijkl,ijk->ikl', x, y); numpy.allclose(z, z2);   # True`. Note the absence of `j` (axis 1) in the output indices, which `einsum` implicitly sums over.

Answer (score 1):

In Theano, none of the dimensions of three and four dimensional tensors are broadcastable. You have to explicitly set them. Then the Numpy principles will work just fine. One way to do this is to use [`T.patternbroadcast`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.patternbroadcast). To read more about broadcasting, refer [this](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html).

You have three dimensions in one of the tensors. So first you need to append a singleton dimension at the end and then make that dimension broadcastable. These two things can be achieved with a single command - [`T.shape_padaxis`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html). The entire code is as follows:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
import numpy as np

X = T.ftensor4('X')
Y = T.ftensor3('Y')
Y_broadcast = T.shape_padaxis(Y, axis=-1)  # appending extra dimension and making it 
                                           # broadcastable
Z = T.sum((X*Y_broadcast), axis=1)  # element-wise multiplication
f = theano.function([X, Y], Z, allow_input_downcast=True)

# Making sure that it works and gives correct results

x = np.random.normal(size=(3, 2, 2, 4))
y = np.random.normal(size=(3, 2, 2))

theano_result = f(x,y)
numpy_result = np.sum(y[:,:,:,np.newaxis] * x, axis=1)
print np.amax(theano_result - numpy_result)  # prints 2.7e-7 on my system, close enough!
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, the sample I posted works almost exactly like that in Theano as well. Since relatively recent versions of Theano, appending a broadcastable axis can be done just as in Numpy: `x[:,:,np.newaxis]` will create an NxMx1 tensor with the third dimension broadcastable.